# Is there a way to send several files over one socket stream simultaneously

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream

I can use in node js the Socket Client to open multiple streams and send them simultaneously, as well as transfer multiple files to the SocketServer over a single socket connection. But I have the problem that I can not distinguish on the socket server, whether it is only one stream, or multiple streams. Is there a way to mark the streams with a separate identifier so that I can separate the streams on the server again?

Server

```
net.createServer((netSocket : net.Socket) => {
    netSocket.on('data', (data) => {
         //No Identifyer 
    })
})
```

Client (Also a server)

```
var client = net.createConnection({
            allowHalfOpen: true,
            host: xxxxx,
            port: xxxxx
        }
var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('1gb.txt');
var fileStream2 = fs.createReadStream('2gb.txt');

fileStream.pipe(client)
fileStream2.pipe(client)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to send something from the client to the server so that the server knows that one file ends and the other begins. You have implement this yourself.

Comment: It makes no sense to send two (or more) files "simultaneously" over a single connection: TCP is just a pipe for bytes, there´s no way to tag bytes to a specific stream. And since the nework connection is serial anyway, sending one file after the other is the way to go (you gain nothing by having two streams in one connection, even if that would be possible). You still need to come up with your own scheme to signal end of one file and beginning of the next (like sending file lenght at the beginning).

Comment: OK thanks for the answer. Since these are streams of users, which "in my case" i can´t put in a queue, I have no choice to start for each user stream, a new client and server between my two servers on a different port?

Comment: You don't need a different port. Just two or more connections.

Comment: Thank you in advance for the helpful support. But I have to ask again, because that does not make sense to me. If I have multiple connections, the server still only has one .on ('data'). The incoming connections / streams still have no identifier, so I can not do the right callbacks. Even if I send before each stream its own information, in which is, which stream to expect and how to handle it, I can not distinguish this in .on ('data'), since the type net.Socket itself also has no identifier. Am I wrong?